# The right way to check arguments data types

Tags: javascript, function, types, arguments, native

I wrote the check of argument's data types inside function body. But I want to create a common function for the check of data types, which will be used in several other functions.
It’s my constructor of “Cat” object:

```
function Cat(name, age, owner) {

    if (!checkArgsDataTypes(arguments.callee, ["string", "number", "Man"])) {
        throw new Error("Incorrect data type of arguments");
    }

    /* Continue function body if data types is correct */

}
```

Here creating  the “Cat” object:

```
var my_cat = new Cat("Tom", 2, new Man());
```

And this my variant of the common check-function:

```
function checkArgsDataTypes(func_link, types_array) {

    var i;
    var current_data_type;

    if (typeof func_link != "function") {
        throw new Error("the first argument must be a function");
    }

    if (types_array instanceof Array) {

        if (func_link.arguments.length != types_array.length) {
            throw new Error("not matching count of arguments and count of array-type items");
        }

        if (types_array.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < types_array.length; i ++) {
                if (typeof types_array[i] != "string") {
                    throw new Error("types_array items must have string data type");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Types array is empty");
        }


        for (i = 0; i < types_array.length; i ++) {

            current_data_type = types_array[i].toLowerCase();

            /* check simple data types */
            if (current_data_type == "string" || current_data_type == "object" || current_data_type == "number") {      
                if (typeof func_link.arguments[i] != current_data_type) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            /* check complex data types */
            else {
                if (func_link.arguments[i].constructor.name != types_array[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;

    }
    else {
        throw new Error("the second argument must be an array");
    }

}
```

I wanna know, what is more less and simply variant of the common function for check data types?
What are your suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You should try typescript :)

Comment: @sychd Using native JavaScript in this code is a bad idea?

Comment: javascript is ok but as you see you need to do a lot of work to check types. On the other hand, in typescript it is from the box. So, if you really need to have typed code it would be good to pay attention to typescript (or flow)

Comment: @sychd Thanks for so wide answer! Ok, I'll look in the TypeScript direction :)